# Three Gallon Jug and 5 Gallon Jug

Tags: calculation-puzzle, decanting-problems

One of the classical puzzles is pouring water into the 5 gallon jug so there is 4 gallons of water remaining. This was popularized by Bruce Willis in "Die Hard with a Vengeance". I was wondering however, if there was a possible way to complete the puzzle using a 3 gallon jug and a 7 gallon jug to still get the 4 gallons.

If so, what other combinations of jugs could you use to still get the same four gallon requirement?

Edit: When doing the 4 gallons remaining from the 7 gallon jug, you must have 1 gallon of water left in the three gallon jug.

Comment: getting 4 gallons with a 3 and a 7 is laughably easy, empty the full 7 gallon into the 3 gallon until the 3 is full, you have $7-3=4$ remaining in the 7 gallon jug

Comment: I think this question would work a little better if it had more info for those unfamiliar with the original problem (and who, sadly, lack the time to go watch DH3 :p)

Comment: @ratchetfreak I forgot the second part of the puzzle.

Comment: If in your edit you mean a little before having 4 in the 7 gallon jug you must have 1 in the 3 gallon jug you can do that.  Fill the 7 from the 3 twice, filling the 3 from the tap five times, and you have 1 in the 3.  Move the 1 to the 7, refill the 3, dump it in the 7 and you have 4.  Otherwise I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Go to the grocery store and buy a 1 gallon water container....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your added constraint of having 1 gallon left in the small jug makes the puzzle impossible.

The only available moves are

- fill a jug from the well, filling it *completely*
- empty a jug into the well, emptying it *completely*
- pour one jug into another, until either one jug is *completely* empty or the other jug is *completely* full

Since these moves leave you with at least one jug either *completely* empty or *completely* full, nothing among these moves lets you end up with both jugs partially filled.

Answer (score 2):

For 7 and 3 wanting 4, just fill the 7 and fill the 3 from it, leaving 4.

Say you had 7 and 3 and want 2.
Fill the 7
fill the 3 from the 7, leaving 4
empty the 3
fill the 3 from the 7, leaving 1
empty the 3
put the 1 in the 3
fill the 7
fill the 3 from the 7, leaving 5
empty the 3
fill the 3 from the 7, leaving 2

Basically you need the desired quantity to be less than the large jug and to have the desired quantity to be a multiple of the least common multiple of the jug volumes.  The algorithm is simple:  fill the large jug, keep filling the small jug from it, refill the large jug when you must, and you will get there.  You are finding a solution to [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)  My solution is 2*7-4*3=2  The solution in the comments is 3*3-1*7=2  Note that if you subtract these two equations you get 3*7-7*3=0

Comment: or fill 3 empty in 7, fill 3 again and empty into 7...

Comment: @ratchetfreak:  yes, you can always go either way around.  I will find a better example.  Even here, you could fill the 3 three times, filling the 7 from it, and be left with 2.

Comment: ...fill 3 empty into 7 until full -> 2 remains in 3

Answer (score 1):

for 2 jugs that can contain $x$ and $y$ you can get any multiple of $GCD(x,y)$ between $0$ and $max(x,y)$ using the algorithm that @Ross described.

You can understand this by creating a new unit so that $1 \text{ unit} = GCD(x,y)$ gallons, and now you have 2 jugs with $\frac x {GCD(x,y)} = x'$ and $\frac y{GCD(x,y)} = y'$ and because you can't take out fractional units it means that you alway have a multiple of $GCD(x,y)$ in your jugs.

Answer (score 0):

Fill the 7 gallon jug, then fill the 3 gallon jug using the water from the 7 gallon jug, repeat this step, now you have excactly 1 gallon left in the 7 gallon jug, and just simply pour that gallon of water over into the 3 gallon jug

Comment: The goal of the puzzle is to have 1 left in the small jug *and* 4 left in the big jug.